# Slideshow Works Strangely

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow

I'm making a slideshow for studying, but it works strangely.
Only first and second li element moves reapeatedly. I can't explain about this phenomenon well.
Here's my code.

```js
timer();
function timer(){
 setInterval(function(){slide()}, 2000);
}
function slide(){
 $('.imgs').animate({left:'-300px'},1000,function(){
  $(this).css({'left':0});
  $(this).append($(this).children('.img').eq(0));
 });
}
```

```css
ul {padding: 0; margin: 0;}
li {list-style: none;}

#box {width: 300px; height: 200px; margin: 50px auto; position: relative; overflow: hidden;}
.imgs {width: 900px; height: 200px; position: relative;}
.img {width: 300px; height: 200px; float: left; position: relative;}

.img:first-child {background: pink;}
.img:nth-child(2) {background: skyblue;}
.img:nth-child(3) {background: grey;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="box">
  <ul class="imgs">
    <li class="img"></li>
    <li class="img"></li>
    <li class="img"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: At the global define a variable for index assign with 0.Then pass it to slide function so get the image accoding to index and ssign it to the div

Comment: var i =0;

timer();
function timer(){
 setInterval(function(){slide(i)}, 2000);
}


function slide(){
 $('.imgs').animate({left:'-300px'},1000,function(){
  $(this).css({'left':0});
  var childs = $(this).children('.img');
  $(this).append(childs[i]);
  i++;
}
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move element -300px until reached total number of li element

If counter reached total number of li element then reset it

After reached last element set -0px

```js
timer();
function timer(){
 setInterval(slide(), 2000);
}
function slide(){
    var imageWidth = 300
    var totalElm = $(".imgs .img").length 
    $('.imgs').width(totalElm*imageWidth)
    var counter = 0 
    return function(){
        var next = counter + 1 
        if(next < totalElm){
            var left = next * imageWidth
            $('.imgs').animate({left:'-'+left+'px'},1000,function(){
                counter++
            });
        }else{
            $('.imgs').animate({left:'-0px'},1000,function(){
                counter = 0
            });
        }
    }
}
```

```css
ul {padding: 0; margin: 0;}
li {list-style: none;}

#box {width: 300px; height: 200px; margin: 50px auto; position: relative; overflow: hidden;}
.imgs {width: 900px; height: 200px; position: relative;}
.img {width: 300px; height: 200px; float: left; position: relative;}

.img:first-child {background: pink;}
.img:nth-child(2) {background: skyblue;}
.img:nth-child(3) {background: grey;}
.img:nth-child(4) {background: red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box">
    <ul class="imgs">
        <li class="img"></li>
        <li class="img"></li>
        <li class="img"></li>
        <li class="img"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```